# Adobe Edge Animate reading a stage variable from within a symbol's action

Tags: jquery, adobe, adobe-edge

I'm struggling with this Edge Animate composition for hours:

What i try to create, is a character selection (multiple images), which will trigger a different text message inside a speech bubble (symbol) for each person.

Along with the individual text I also have 2 input fields (select2.js) which reside between the text spans. For that I had to generate the text spans and input fields in the **symbol's creationComplete action** like this:

```
    perscontent.html('<span style="font-weight: bold;">'+perstext[0]+'<br></span>'+
                    '<span>'+perstext[1]+'</span>'+
                    '<input id="tech" class="bubbleinput" style="margin-top: 5px" type="text" data-position="top" placeholder="mit der Technologie:"></input>'+
                    '<span>'+perstext[2]+'</span>'+
                    '<input id="probl" class="bubbleinput" style="margin-top: 5px" type="text" data-position="top" placeholder="das Problem/Produkt:"></input>'+
                    '<span>'+perstext[3]+'</span></p> ');
```

As you can see there is the array variable `perstext` which takes the values from another array (containing the individual text) depending on the value of the **stage variable "perstoggle"** which I set in the stage **action > compositionReady** : `sym.setVariable("perstoggle", "pers1select");`

**► And here is the point where the pain starts!** I'm not able to read `perstoggle`:

```
    var cur = sym.getComposition().getStage().getVariable("perstoggle");
    console.log( "=> ", cur);
```

On the console log it displays "undefined"...ANY ADVICE? Thanks alot in advance!

//EDIT
On the other hand if I read the `perstoggle` stage variable from inside the callback function, it suddenly displays the correct value ("pers1text") on the console. But my jquery select2 inputs are not being loaded:

```
    yepnope({

both: [

                    "select2.min.js",
                    "select2.css",
                    "pagestyle.css"

        ],

    callback: function(){


                    $("#tech").select2(......);

                    $("#probl").select2(.....);

                    var cur = sym.getComposition().getStage().getVariable("perstoggle");
                    console.log( "=> ", cur);

                    switch (cur){
                    case ("pers1select"): var perstext = pers1text;
                    break;

                    default : var perstext = pers2text;
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not keep it simple?

(simple example)

open the code window in edge animate 
( menu -> window > code ) 
click on stage 
and add this code:

```
var perstext;
perstext = "begin"; 
var foo = function() {
   $("#Stage_Rectangle").html('<span style="font-weight:bold;">'+perstext+'</span>');
};// will set the text on div Retan
```

this will make the function foo that updates the perstext global.

first you need to make it run at the beginning. 
so to do that add stage > compositionready and add this code:

```
foo();
```

this will run the function foo at the beginning

and to change it to something else add a click event on a div or image
and just add this code:

```
perstext = "i changed!";
foo();
```

and that will change the perstext and update it again through foo();